# How to get an id , baseUri from jQuery object and use it as string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Jquery object like the example below

```
[li#myid.item.fr-hide, prevObject: _.fn.init[1], context: a.link.pjaxload]0: li#myid.item.fr-hidecontext: a.link.pjaxloadlength: 1prevObject: _.fn.init[1]__proto__: _[0]
```

The object has an arrow pointing down and when i click the arrow , there are some other variable arrows namely `0: li#myid.item.fr-hide`,accesskey etc. And when i click the 0, there are some more collections and among which is the baseUri.The baseUri contains a string uri with the part of the string which is myid.
I want to compare and check that object all the time if part of that baseUri example

`//www.mydomain.com/myid?l=FR`

contains myid . I tried everything possible but because my object is not a string i just count get it going/comparing

i tried.

```
   if(/myid/i.test($active.item.get(0).outerHTML){
}
```

It failed.

I tried

```
if(/myid/i.test($active.item.id.outerHTML){
}
```

It failed. I tried many more that i lost count. Note myid is an element that has id and its id is what i am after. But the id is also contain in the baseUri. Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to check if baseuri contains string "myid" ?

Comment: Could you please display your `object` so it can be readable? Use jsFiddle or the snippet feature located in the toolbar (icon looks like a page with < >)

Answer (score 0):

I finally get it going. active.item is a jQuery object. Below is what works for me

```
var $elementid = active.item.get(0).id;

if(active.item) {
   if(page.language() === 'FR' && /myid/i.test($elementid)){
    //My code
   }
}
```

Another issue i encounter was `var $elementid = active.item.get(0).id;` passed my element id value to `$elementid`. However

```
if(page.language() === 'FR' && /myid/i.test($active.item.get(0).id)){
        //My code
       }
```

The above failed and always return false. When i log `active.item.get(0).id` on the console, it turns out it returns an object not my id . This i am not sure though , looking for a better explanation as well.